# How to insert the list of row objects in Mysql using java?

Tags: java, mysql, list, arraylist

I have a list of row object wherein each row has some fields something like this

```
myList= [ shridhar, 1234, 2015-10-30 3:44 , someMessage, 8;
          sahil,4534, 2015-10-29 13:44 , someMessage, 18;
          shubham, 3234, 2015-10-10 12:24 , someMessage, 9]
```

I want the list data to store it in MySql database with different fields, I'm stuck in how to set the multiple values while querying, as I'm making use of `setString()` of `PreparedStatement` class method which takes only two arguments.
I have tried something like this:

```
String query= "INSERT INTO facebooktable(name, id, date, msg, score)" + "VALUES( ?,?,?,?,?)";
             PreparedStatement preStatement= connection.prepareStatement(query);
             for(int index=0; index<=myList.size();index++){
                 rowObj=myList.get(index);
                 preStatement.setString() // allows only two parameters

             }
```

How do I pass multiple values making use of the `PreparedStatement` class?

Comment: You'll need to do that manually for each field, because they are not all strings - some are dates, some are numbers. At least I assume that's how your table is declared in mySQL. It's not so hard to write 5 statements.

Comment: You mean to say something like **preStatement.setString(index, rowObj.getName());**
**preStatement.setString(index, rowObj.getName());**
     
within the loop?

Comment: I mean that you should use `setString` for the string parameter (1),  `setInt` for the int parameter (2) and so on. But you should give the exact declaration of your list's type, and the definition of the table. I believe this was marked as the wrong duplicate, but I can't say for sure unless you provide more info by editing the question.